# How to make WPF Shapes Completely Filled

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I have a path like this,

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#CCCCFF">
    <Path.Data>
    <PathGeometry>
        <PathFigure StartPoint="6.0,12.5" >
            <LineSegment Point="50.0,6.0"></LineSegment>
            <LineSegment Point="94.0,12.5"></LineSegment>
            <LineSegment Point="60.0,19.0"></LineSegment>
            <LineSegment Point="20.0,19.0"></LineSegment>
            <LineSegment Point="6.0,12.5"></LineSegment>
        </PathFigure>
        <PathFigure StartPoint="7.97852754592896,12.2077178955078">
            <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Point="4.02147245407104,12.7922821044922" RotationAngle="171.59663391113281" Size="2,4" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"></ArcSegment>
            <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Point="7.97852754592896,12.2077178955078" RotationAngle="171.59663391113281" Size="2,4" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"></ArcSegment>
        </PathFigure>
        <PathFigure StartPoint="51.9785270690918,6.29228210449219">
            <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Point="48.0214729309082,5.70771789550781" RotationAngle="188.40336608886719" Size="2,4" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"></ArcSegment>
            <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Point="51.9785270690918,6.29228210449219" RotationAngle="188.40336608886719" Size="2,4" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"></ArcSegment>
        </PathFigure>
    </PathGeometry>
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

It represents a polygon with some circles at a couple of the corners.

One of the circles is not filled in correctly. It happens to be part of the circle that covers the polygon.

It reminds me of graphics that use XOR. Put two over the top of each other and they cancel out.

If I remove the polygon (the linesegments) then it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In looking at your Path and playing around with the [PathGeometry.FillRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry.fillrule.aspx) Property I am getting the same results for both of the options.

This is using the Nonzero FilRule with a single `Path`.
[image]

The only way that I was able to get the results I beleive you are looking for was to use the `Nonzero FillRule` and create a seperate path for the problem PathFigure's.

This is using the Nonzero FillRule with a seperate `Path` for the problem `PathFigures`.
[image]

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#CCCCFF">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero">
            <PathFigure StartPoint="6.0,12.5" >
                <LineSegment Point="50.0,6.0"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="94.0,12.5"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="60.0,19.0"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="20.0,19.0"></LineSegment>
                <LineSegment Point="6.0,12.5"></LineSegment>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="#CCCCFF">
    <Path.Data >
        <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero">
            <PathFigure StartPoint="51.9785270690918,6.29228210449219">
                <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Point="48.0214729309082,5.70771789550781" RotationAngle="188.40336608886719" Size="2,4" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"></ArcSegment>
                <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Point="51.9785270690918,6.29228210449219" RotationAngle="188.40336608886719" Size="2,4" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"  ></ArcSegment>
            </PathFigure>
            <PathFigure StartPoint="7.97852754592896,12.2077178955078" >
                <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Point="4.02147245407104,12.7922821044922" RotationAngle="171.59663391113281" Size="2,4" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"></ArcSegment>
                <ArcSegment IsLargeArc="True" Point="7.97852754592896,12.2077178955078" RotationAngle="171.59663391113281" Size="2,4" SweepDirection="Counterclockwise"></ArcSegment>
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Comment: OK, this looks promising. I was thinking that the circles wouldn't cover over the corners in the polygon. Adding in lower alpha channels for both fill values does what I was after. This is required anyway because these shapes are being plotted on a map. This requires the background to be visible through the shape so the user can see the roads when drawing the shape.

Answer (score 0):

On your PathGeometry element try setting

```
FillRule="NonZero"
```

The default of EvenOdd gives the XOR behavior you're describing.

Comment: Yeah it is bizarre that. Someone else mentioned that to me and it does seem like the answer, but it made no difference. Thanks.